# Jquery.Validate() on identical forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to override the default error styling in jQuery.Validate(). Instead of having the default settings printing out a dark-red label I tried to style it's div parent instead. So here's the deal: 
I have two identical forms, (a web editor can choose how many he or she wants), on the same page. Each form shares the same class : '.formClass'.

The code below is defined in the $(document).ready scope and setting up the "rules {} list" for all the required fields.

```
    $(".formClass").find("input[data-val-required]").each(function () {
    var name = $(this).attr("name").toLowerCase();
    if (name.match("email")) {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            email: true
        });
    }
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
});
```

and heres the main function :

```
$(".formClass").validate({
//errorLabelContainer: '#testestets', //Displays a collection of the generated error messages 
focusInvalid: true,
errorElement: "div",
wrapper: 'div', // a wrapper around the error message
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-field').addClass("errorOnThis");
},
messages: {
    name: {
        required: "testing..",
    },
},

invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    alert(errors);

},
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass);
}
```

});

The form only have two required fields: Name and Email. 
If i post the form with lets say a null value for Name. It will highlight the input along with my desired styling. However, if I post it again without changing the name to a valid value the form submits regardless of any invalid inputs. Why?

Another question, Only my first form is getting these custom changes, my second form, which looks identical to the first one, still gets the default error messages. Confused.

Is there a way to handle errors on callback like `

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {

     $(element).parents("form:first").find("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if (!element.isValid()) {
            highlight(element, errorclass, validClass);
        } else {
           $(element).parents("form:first").find("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");            }

    }`
```

I tried it but it didn't work so if anyone can find the flaws in my code i would be forever thankful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I'm trying to override the default error styling in jQuery.Validate(). Instead of having the default settings printing out a dark-red label I tried to style it's div parent instead."

There is nothing in the jQuery Validate plugin that styles the error messages.  It simply creates the HTML markup for the message and applies the `error` class.  It's up to you to create the CSS.  So if it's dark red, then that's something in your CSS causing this, not the plugin.

> I have two identical forms, (a web editor can choose how many he or she wants), on the same page. Each form shares the same class : '.formClass'.
>
> ....
>
> Only my first form is getting these custom changes, my second form, which looks identical to the first one, still gets the default error messages. Confused.

You **cannot** attach `.validate()` to a jQuery selector that represents more than one element.  If you want the same settings applied to two forms using the same class name, then you'll need a jQuery `.each()`.  Otherwise only the first form is attached to `.validate()`.

```
$(".formClass").each(function() {
    $(this).validate({ 
        // your options
    });
});
```

Regarding your code here:

```
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if (!element.isValid()) {
        highlight(element, errorclass, validClass);  // <-????
    ....
```

There is no such thing as `highlight()` and this would break your code.  `highlight` is an option of the `.validate()` method, not a function you can just insert wherever you want.

Also, you would not be enabling/disabling the button within `highlight/unhighlight`.  `highlight` and `unhighlight` are meant for adding/removing classes on individual form fields as these form fields become valid/invalid.  **Anything you put inside `highlight/unhighlight` will over-ride the default behavior.**  If you want to toggle the `disable` attribute of the button, you would probably want to use `submitHandler` and `invalidHandler` options, where `submitHandler` fires on a valid form and `invalidHandler` fires on an invalid form.